# Could not initialize proxy - no Session: reattach entity

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I need an experimented person's point of view.
What I am trying to do is a voting system. I have a list of demand, u can vote either: ok or ko.

### In myJSP:

### Demand | ok | ko |

If the person hits ok/ko I send an ajax query to my servlet, which checks if the person has already voted on this demand, otherwise it saves the vote.

in my servlet:

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Demande demande = daoDemande.get(id);

        User user = (User)request.getSession().getAttribute("membre");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if(!demande.hasVoted(user)){
            Vote vote = new Vote();
            vote.setDemande(demande);
            vote.setAuteur(user);
            if(request.getParameter("vote").equals("Pour"))
                vote.setVote(true);
            else
                vote.setVote(false);

            daoVote.save(vote);

            demande.setVote(vote);
            daoDemande.save(demande);

            out.println( "<h4>Votre vote a été pris en copmte!</h4>" );
        }
        else            
            out.println( "<h4>Vous avez déjà voté!</h4>" ); 
}
```

I get the exception mentioned above when the person votes another time on the same demand.
Can any one tell me where is the problem??

daoVote.save method:

```
@Override
    public void save(Vote vote) throws Exception {
        Session session = DAOHBM.getInstance().connect();
        if(vote.getId() == -1)
            session.save(vote);
        else
            session.update(vote);
        DAOHBM.getInstance().close(session);
    }
```

DAOHBM.connect:

```
public Session connect() throws Exception {
        if (sessionFactory == null)
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();//null le prof ma darhe ev sa solution!!
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        return session;
    }
```

DAOHBM.close:

```
public void close(Session session) throws Exception {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

The exception:

```
févr. 11, 2014 1:44:33 PM org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor processException
Avertissement: Unhandled Exception thrown: class org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException
févr. 11, 2014 1:44:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [/Cahier_de_charge] threw exception [org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session] with root cause
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
    at metier.User_$$_javassist_0.equals(User_$$_javassist_0.java)
    at metier.Demande.hasVoted(Demande.java:46)
    at action.ActionVoteUneDemande.execute(ActionVoteUneDemande.java:37)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This is so weird to me, cuz when I re-vote for the first demand no exception!